# Refactor code to delete a record

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

```
 if (StockLocationRecordsToBeDeleted != null)
 {
     foreach (int _serverId in StockLocationRecordsToBeDeleted)
     {
         StockLocation_Record RecordToRemove = db.StockLocation_Record.Where(x => x.ServerLocationId == _serverId).FirstOrDefault();

         if (RecordToRemove != null)
         {
             db.StockLocation_Record.DeleteObject(RecordToRemove);
             db.SaveChanges();
         }
     }
}
```

This successfuly removes a record, but do I have to create a new `StockLocation_Record` first, can't I just `DeleteObject(RecordToRemove).Where(ServerId == _serverId)`

Comment: Sure you can, but then you most probably will end up using `try-catch` and I don't think you achieve a lot by doing this.

Comment: If your code is working and all you need is opinions about it, try [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: ok thanks guys...its already all inside a try-catch and a transaction

Comment: your code seems good for me